# Perfect square root recurrence

Tags: roots, square-numbers

Spent some time trying to find some recurrence for determine bigger than current perfect square but unsuccessful. 
For example: current 121 and next 144. Who is next after 144? 
Can someone help me to take this recurrence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

The well-known formula for $(n+1)^2$ can be written as
$(n+1)^2=n^2+n+(n+1)$.

Comment: `n` is current number? I don't really get. If current 121, how get next perfect square 144 using this formula?

Comment: Yes, $n$ is the current number, the square thereof is known. For instance, as $121=11^2$, $\;12^2=121+(11+12)$.

Comment: ohh. got it. thank you!

Answer (score 2):

As $(n+1)^2 = n^2 + 2n + 1$, letting $f(n) = n^2$, we get -$$f(n+1) = f(n) + 2n+1$$